# \centerline{} command alternative?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I am adding figures to a work and most of the figures are too wide and are thus not centered but are shifted to the right. I searched here and found a solution, that would consist in adding the `\centerline{}` command into the figure environment. This work fine for figures added with the command `\includegraphics{}`, like in this example:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\centerline{\includegraphics{SOIR_optics}}
\end{center} % is this really useful?
\end{figure}
```

But when I try to add a `tikzpicture` instead, this solution does not work (see example)

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\centerline{\begin{tikzpicture} 
some code 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

My question is : are there alternatives to this `\centerline{}` command?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your picture wider than the margins of the page?

Comment: Yes, for some of them

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `\centerline` command should never be used in a LaTeX document (unless you know precisely what you're doing, and probably only in the preamble for some definition). Use

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

<whatever>

\end{figure}
```

and `<whatever>` (a graphic, a TikZ picture or anything) will be centered.

Comment: This does not work for figures slightly larger than the margins :/

Comment: @mwoua Why don't you simply scale down the image to fit the textwidth? That would make more sense...

Comment: If I scale it down, some details could be unreadable.

Comment: @mwoua: of course that depends on _how_ do you perform the scaling; without details is impossible to say more.

Comment: @mwoua If you need that, enclose the object to be scaled in `\makebox[\columnwidth]{...}`

Comment: @egreg, If I'm not so wrong (actually I'm almost certain), you mentioned not to use `\centerline` in an other question as well. What is so devil about it?

Comment: @egreg, How would you solve http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8610/how-to-center-large-figures-in-latex-and-how-to-fix-short-justified-lines without `\centerline`?

Comment: @Royi `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}`

Comment: @Pouya https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311293/centerline-ignores-page-margin

Answer (score 4):

You can use `adjustbox`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  %%  export option makes adjustbox --
                                %%  -- goodies available inside includegraphics command
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
X\hrulefill X
\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth,center]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is very useful for figures that are wider than `\textwidth`. Another useful macro will be `adjustbox` environment with `max width` option.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
X\hrulefill X

This is resized to \verb|1.1\textwidth|
\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{adjustbox}{center,max width=1.1\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,center]{example-image-a}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
The following is not resized:
\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{adjustbox}{center,max width=1.1\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth,center]{example-image-b}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

The advantage of `max width` is that the content is resized only if it exceeds the `max width` otherwise not.

**With `tikzpicture` environment**

I assume that your tikz picture are saved as separate files. Then using `adjustbox` and `tikzscale` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,tikz,tikzscale}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myfig.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \draw[use as bounding box](-20,-20) rectangle (20,20);
    \node at (0,0) (A) {A};
    \node[above right] (B) at (A.north east) {B};
    \draw (A.south west)--(B.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
X\hrulefill X

This is resized to \verb|1.1\textwidth|
\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1.1\textwidth,center}
\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{myfig.tikz}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
The following is not resized:
\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1.1\textwidth,center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{myfig.tikz}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! This works for \includegraphics. 
But for a tikzpicture environment?

Comment: @mwoua You can use tikzscale package. Give me a minute. I will provide an example.

Comment: I will not use it now but I keep it in mind. Thank you so much for your answer!