# Why I can't insert image with the following code?

Tags: graphics

I tried to insert an image with the following line, but it doesn't work, keeps saying the image doesn't exist. Why is that?

```
    \includegraphics{{C:/Users/XYZ/Pictures/Rplot01.jpg}}
```

Comment: I think I'll just use the online editor, much easier. Thanks, not only I'm new to Tex.Se, I'm pretty new to Tex as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of an `includegraphics` line of code:

```
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{kSED7}
```

To look at this a little more carefully, after the backslash and command, there are the optional brackets to specify width, height, and ratio, and then (the important part) there are curly braces. You should only have one set of curly braces.

Then, I don't know what you are using for your LaTeX editor, but I use an online LaTeX editor. The way you enter the image name on this particular editor is not like you have specified. [In the online editor](https://www.sharelatex.com/) the image should appear off to the left, like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Then, you simply type in kSED7 or YKjf6 instead of the full line you did.

**The main thing** I would say to try is to use only one set of curly braces instead of two.

Finally, also be sure to use the line

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

at the very beginning of your LaTeX document.

**Update:**

In light of your comment, you can center a graphic by using the command

```
\centerline{}
```

with your `\includegraphics{}` function inside the curly braces. An example of this would be

```
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{kSED7}}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting, I tried the online editor, and it still didn't work even though I see the correct file name on the left column!

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange. Oh! Did you include the line at the very beginning \usepackage{graphicx} - this would be before you list the title or anything.

Comment: Ok, now it works. I read somewhere that line isn't necessary. Thanks anyway, now I've to figure how to configure the graph.

Comment: What do you mean by "configure the graph"? Centering it?

Comment: @mackbox, I'm not sure what you mean by "configure the graph" but to center it, you can type \centerline{} with your \includegraphic{} function inside the curly braces of the \centerline{} function.

Comment: @mackbox, no problem, glad to help!

Comment: Heather, are you really suggesting somebody to use `\centerline`?

Comment: @Johannes_B, yes....I am new to LaTeX, but I thought that was the accepted way to do it, especially if only for one line of code. Is it not...?

Comment: `\centering` used in a group.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I'm not absolutely sure what that means.

Comment: [\centerline{} command alternative?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163572)

Comment: @mackbox, it would be better to use [what is suggested here in the answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163572/centerline-command-alternative) than `\centerline`; my apologies.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, we all started once :-)