# Align Abbreviations and Nomenclature with the acro package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, acronyms, nomenclature, acro

Ahoj,

I got a little issue concerning the [acro](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package. I want my abbreviations and nomenclature to aligned.

Let's say I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\acsetup{first-style=short}

\DeclareAcronym{ihp}{
short = IHP,
long = Inner Helmholtz Plane,
class = abbrev
}

\DeclareAcronym{ohp}{
short = OHP,
long = Outer Helmholtz Plane,
class = abbrev
}

\begin{document}

The layer of water dipoles and ions with hydrogen envelope, which forms
in this way at the boundary surface, is called the Helmholtz layer and
extend into an inner Helmholtz plane (\ac{ihp}) and an outer Helmholtz
plane (\ac{ohp}).

\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]

\end{document}
```

[image]

But the long names of the Acronyms should be aligned.
Is there a way align them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the environment used by `\printacronyms` from `description` (the default) to `longtable` from the [`longtable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package.  In `\ac-setup` the `list-style` option controls this, to place it in a `longtable` environment you can simply use `list-style=longtable` (or there are a number of alternative options).

The `\DeclareAcroListStyle` even allows development of your own style to place the list in for further customisation as documented in the [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) manual.

With `list-style=longtable` (extra O added to acronym to emphasise the alignment)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{acro}

\acsetup{first-style=short,list-style=longtable}

\DeclareAcronym{ihp}{
short = IHP,
long = Inner Helmholtz Plane,
class = abbrev
}

\DeclareAcronym{ohp}{
short = OOHP,
long = Outer Helmholtz Plane,
class = abbrev
}

\begin{document}

The layer of water dipoles and ions with hydrogen envelope, which forms
in this way at the boundary surface, is called the Helmholtz layer and
extend into an inner Helmholtz plane (\ac{ihp}) and an outer Helmholtz
plane (\ac{ohp}).

\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I know it's an old topic, but I had the same problem. Is it possible to use this longtable-option and also align the abbreviations on the left (delete the offset to the right)?

Comment: @Knallbert I think you'd have to define a new list template based on the existing `longtable` style, the column types are hardcoded at the moment.  If you want to open a new question I may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are other options with which you can fine-tune spacing and location.

```latex
% Abbreviations setup
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{longtable}

\setlength\LTleft{18pt}  % Adjust the left margin
\setlength\LTpre{-6pt}   % Adjust the space above the table

\acsetup{
  list/template = longtable,
  list/heading = none,
  templates/colspec = {l@{\hspace{2cm}}l} % Adjust the space as needed
}

\DeclareAcronym{ihp}{
short = IHP,
long = Inner Helmholtz Plane,
class = abbrev
}

\DeclareAcronym{ohp}{
short = OOHP,
long = Outer Helmholtz Plane,
class = abbrev
}


\begin{document}

The layer of water dipoles and ions with hydrogen envelope, which forms
in this way at the boundary surface, is called the Helmholtz layer and
extend into an inner Helmholtz plane (\ac{ihp}) and an outer Helmholtz
plane (\ac{ohp}).

\chapter*{\centerline{List of Abbreviations and Terms}}\label{ch:terms}
\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=none]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `list/preamble` to set `\LTleft`/`\LTpre` locally might be better. I don't see the advantage of `heading=none` and a manual `\chapter*`, and [`\centerline` is probably best avoided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163576/106162).