# Center Extra-Wide Table in Page, depsite exceeding \textwidth

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am currently writing a report and have some problems with an extra wide table. I Would like to have it centered on the page, however it always algins left due to the overfull \hbox. I have made progress in making the table thinner, but not enough.

I have also seen the answers in [How can I center a too wide table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39435/how-can-i-center-a-too-wide-table) and [How do I center this wide table in LaTeX?](http://How%20do%20I%20center%20this%20wide%20table%20in%20LaTeX?), however I have not been capable to implement the solution proposed. Maybe there is some incomaptibility with some packages I use.

I have tried to put below a MWE of my problem, I have however inserted all the packages I use in case anybody sees where the incompatibility is.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} %EINSEITIG
\usepackage[a4paper , lmargin = {3cm} , rmargin = {3cm} , tmargin = {2.5cm} , bmargin = {2.5cm}, headheight=14.5pt]{geometry} %für PC Ansicht


\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb} 
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[font=small,format=hang]{caption} 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{selectp} 
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 


% SI-Unit
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol,exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx}


% HyperRef Formatting
\usepackage[pdftex, colorlinks, linkcolor=black, frenchlinks, unicode]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{citecolor=black}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}


\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}



\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.75} %Definition der neuen Farbe Grau


    \usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Huge}{\thechapter.\quad}{0em}{} 
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}}



\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}

%%PDF-Einstellungen

\fancyhead[L]{Version 1.4 - \today}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{}

\pagenumbering{roman} %Römische Ziffern

%%

%
A tabular listing with DIN standards and corresponding ASTM standards for the aforementioned testing methods is given in \autoref{Tab:test}.


\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{DIN and ASTM Test Method Standards Comparison}
\begin{tabular}{llcc}
\toprule 
Field & Test & DIN-Standard & ASTM-Standard \\
\toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{Concrete} & Compressive strength (UCS) & EN~12390-3 & C39/C39M Bananenequark \\ 
& Young's modulus & EN 12390-13 &  C469/C469M \\
& Triaxial Tests & - & C801* \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\begin{scriptsize}  * = standard withdrawn \end{scriptsize}} \\
\end{tabular}
\label{Tab:test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have tried many options but still have no look and the table is aligned to the left of the text.

**Can somebody provide me with a solution how I can center the table on the page and not align it left in the text?**

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Both the options given in the accepted answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435/ work for your table, that is either `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\begin{tabular}{llcc} ... \end{tabular}}` or `\begin{adjustbox}{center} \begin{tabular}{llcc} ... \end{tabular} \end{adjustbox}`.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: What's a "Bananenequark"? :-)

Comment: @Mico: Banenquark ist just a word I invented, because I have citations within the table, which I have taken out in the MWE.  
A Bananenquark is a banana curd actually ;)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Great! That actually worked for me... 
Don´t know why i didn#manage that beforee! Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your table can be fit in text width with use of the `tabular*` table environment and left adjust `\colsep` to it. using `\small` font size make table even nicer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} %EINSEITIG
\usepackage[hmargin = {3cm},
            vmargin = {2.5cm} ,
            headheight=14.5pt]{geometry} %für PC Ansicht
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[font=small,format=hang]{caption}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage[colorlinks, frenchlinks, unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
A tabular listing with DIN standards and corresponding ASTM standards for the aforementioned testing methods is given in \autoref{Tab:test}.

    \begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Comparison of DIN and ASTM Test Method Standards}
\label{Tab:test}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \small% works also with normal font size
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llll}
    \toprule
Field & Test & DIN Standard & ASTM Standard \\
    \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Concrete} & Compressive strength (UCS)
& EN~12390-3 & C39/C39M Bananen\-equark \\
& Young's modulus & EN 12390-13 & C469/C469M \\
& Triaxial Tests  & --           & C801* \\
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\scriptsize * = standard withdrawn}\\
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Impressive solution, and actually pretty much ideal. It's pretty tight with the spacing in my table with normal font, but a great solution. Will definitely be handy for other tables!

Answer (score 5):

Since you're already loading the `tabularx` package, you might consider employing a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. I suggest using a (modified) `X` column type for the final column and allowing line breaks in that column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} %EINSEITIG
\usepackage[hmargin = {3cm}, vmargin = {2.5cm} ,
    headheight=14.5pt]{geometry} %für PC Ansicht

\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.75} % neue Farbe Grau

\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[font=small,format=hang]{caption}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{selectp}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

% SI-Unit
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol,exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx}

\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Huge}{\thechapter.\quad}{0em}{}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}}

% HyperRef Formatting (load 'hyperref' package LAST)
\usepackage[colorlinks, frenchlinks, unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\pagenumbering{roman} % Römische Ziffern

%%PDF-Einstellungen
\fancyhead[L]{Version 1.4 -- \today}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}

A tabular listing with DIN standards and corresponding ASTM standards for the aforementioned testing methods is given in \autoref{Tab:test}.

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Comparison of DIN and ASTM Test Method Standards}
\label{Tab:test}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lllL@{}}
\toprule
Field & Test & DIN Standard & ASTM Standard \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{Concrete} & Compressive strength (UCS) 
& EN~12390-3 & C39/C39M Bananen\-equark \\
& Young's modulus & EN 12390-13 & C469/C469M \\
& Triaxial Tests  & --           & C801* \\
\bottomrule \addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\scriptsize * = standard withdrawn}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. As mentioned above "Bananequark" is actually a placeholder for `\cite{..}` that's why your solution doesn't work for my purpouse (I can't split my literature style abbrv in two lines). But it might be useful to seombedoy else ;)

Answer (score 5):

I know that this will trigger some comments but you could just use `\centerline` and wrap it around your table. This does what you seem to be looking for. Whether or not this is good style is a different question.

```
\centerline{\begin{tabular}{llcc}
\toprule 
Field & Test & DIN-Standard & ASTM-Standard \\
\toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{Concrete} & Compressive strength (UCS) & EN~12390-3 & C39/C39M Bananenequark \\ 
& Young's modulus & EN 12390-13 &  C469/C469M \\
& Triaxial Tests & - & C801* \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\begin{scriptsize}  * = standard withdrawn \end{scriptsize}} \\
\end{tabular}}
```

Comment: So you're not disappointed by lack of comments: You seem to have some feeling that `\centerline` is not good style, so why post an answer with it, when other options are available (and linked to in the question)? (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163576/ by the way.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry, I simply do not share the sentiments of your link. Did you read what is written there? It says one should use `\centering`, which however does not achieve what the OP wants. What I meant by style is having tables overshoot, not the use of `\centerline`. So far I have been left completely in the dark *why* `\centerline` is not to be used.

Comment: I know what is written there, and I know it doesn't answer the "why". If you look in the comments though, you'll see mentioned `\makebox[\textwidth]{<tabular>}` just as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435/ which is mentioned in the question. The purpose of the link was mainly to point to someone with a bit more authority than me, saying that `\centerline` should not be used in LaTeX. (I don't know the technical reason for it, so cannot help with that.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. So we are stuck at this point, right? We can either assume that this authority is always absolutely right, which may be a good assumption, or question why he did not bother to reply to the comments asking this. I personally agree 99% with that authority, but I also do have a few disagreements, It might well be that `\makebox` is better, I do not know enough to judge this. In any case, your comment is well-taken, and will provide additional information to those who read these lines.

Comment: Some more technical info here (and now I'll stop making noise): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311293/centerline-ignores-page-margin/311294#311294

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am actually grateful for the comments and there are obviously many things that I do not know. (But if I read the thing correctly, this is a situation in which it does *not* lead to a problem, do you agree?)

Comment: Yes, it would seem so.

Comment: @Marmot: Many thanks for your solution. It actually does just what I need. It might be no nice style, but it does the job and that was my question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Thaks for your comments and your solution above. It did the job for me too :)