# Centering group plot figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

Can anyone show me how to center this `group plot`?  I've tried every trick in the tex.stackexchange book of similar posts (e.g., [How to center large figures in LaTeX and how to fix short justified lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8610/how-to-center-large-figures-in-latex-and-how-to-fix-short-justified-lines)).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, alphalph}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
      \begin{groupplot}[
         group style={group size=3 by 2, vertical sep=70pt,
    ylabels at=edge left
    },
          view={0}{90},
          width=5.2cm,
          height=5.2cm,
      scale only axis,
      scaled ticks = false,
      tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
      title={My title},
      xlabel={x-axis},
      ylabel={y-axis}],
          unbounded coords=jump]
        ]
        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 1}}]       
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 2}}]      
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 3}}]      
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 4}}]      
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 5}}]      
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

         \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your plots are too wide. You may try to put 2 plots in a row instead of 3. However, there is always this box techniques that can be used.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, alphalph}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
      \begin{groupplot}[
         group style={group size=3 by 2, vertical sep=70pt,
    ylabels at=edge left
    },
          view={0}{90},
          width=5.2cm,
          height=5.2cm,
      scale only axis,
      scaled ticks = false,
      tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
      title={My title},
      xlabel={x-axis},
      ylabel={y-axis}],
          unbounded coords=jump]
        ]
        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 1}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 2}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 3}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 4}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 5}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

         \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{figure}




\end{document}
```

[image]

If in case, you want to center the last two plots, you may use a suitable width for all plots (so that you know how much to shift) and use `xshift` like

```
\nextgroupplot [xshift=1.2in,title={\it{Title 4}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [xshift=1.2in,title={\it{Title 5}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };
```

[image]

With `table`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, alphalph}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
  A   B      
  1    4
  2    6
  3    9
  4    2
  5    3
  \end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
      \begin{groupplot}[
         group style={group size=3 by 2, vertical sep=70pt,
    ylabels at=edge left
    },
          view={0}{90},
          width=5.2cm,
          height=5.2cm,
      scale only axis,
      scaled ticks = false,
      tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
      title={My title},
      xlabel={x-axis},
      ylabel={y-axis}],
          unbounded coords=jump]
        ]
        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 1}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    table[x=A,y=B]{mydata.dat};

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 2}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    table[x=A,y=B]{mydata.dat};

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 3}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    table[x=A,y=B]{mydata.dat};

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 4}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    table[x=A,y=B]{mydata.dat};

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 5}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    table[x=A,y=B]{mydata.dat};

         \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{figure}




\end{document}
```

and with

```
        \nextgroupplot [xshift=1.2in,title={\it{Title 4}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    table[x=A,y=B]{mydata.dat};

        \nextgroupplot [xshift=1.2in,title={\it{Title 5}}]
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    table[x=A,y=B]{mydata.dat};
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please show how to use the `table` environment in place of `coordinates`?  For some reason, this code does not work (yet) with `table {}`  Please just add a new section to your answer, do not delete anything you have written, it is very useful.

Comment: @warship Certainly, see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative: add `\hspace*{-4cm}` (adjust how many centimeters you want to achieve a nice centering).  For example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, alphalph}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\hspace*{-4cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
      \begin{groupplot}[
         group style={group size=3 by 2, vertical sep=70pt,
    ylabels at=edge left
    },
          view={0}{90},
          width=5.2cm,
          height=5.2cm,
      scale only axis,
      scaled ticks = false,
      tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
      title={My title},
      xlabel={x-axis},
      ylabel={y-axis}],
          unbounded coords=jump]
        ]
        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 1}}]       
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 2}}]      
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 3}}]      
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 4}}]      
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

        \nextgroupplot [title={\it{Title 5}}]      
\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
        };

         \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}



\end{document}
```

[image]