# centering image relative to page (skipping margins)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, includegraphics

I am looking for a way to center images independent of the predefined border margins. As you can see, image A is centered relative to the text. B is somthing wrong completly or in other words does not ignore the text-margin. C is a try but I would like to auto center the image (even overlapping the margin text).
 Thanks in Advance.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[paperheight=28cm, paperwidth=14cm,%
top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1cm, right=2.5cm,%
]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\grey}[1]{\textcolor[gray]{.66}{#1}}

\DeclareNewLayer[
background,
evenpage,
leftmargin,
contents={%
    \vfil\hfil\rotatebox{90}{%
        \fontsize{60}{100}\selectfont\grey\leftmark%
    }\hfil\vfil
}]{markmargin-left}
\DeclareNewLayer[
background,
oddpage,
rightmargin,
contents={%
    \vfil\hfil\rotatebox{-90}{%
        \fontsize{60}{100}\selectfont\grey\rightmark%
    }\hfil\vfil
}]{markmargin-right}

\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{markmargin}{markmargin-left,markmargin-right}
\pagestyle{markmargin}


%\automark[section]{section}
\manualmark
\renewcommand\section[1]{%
    \clearpage%
    \markboth{\textit{#1}}{\textit{#1}}
}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
    \section{A.1 test page}
    \blindtext
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=.8]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}

    \clearpage
    \section{A.2 test page}
    \blindtext
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=.8]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}

    \clearpage
    \section{B.1 test page}
    \blindtext
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \makebox[\paperwidth][c]{\includegraphics[scale=.8]{example-image-b}}
    \end{figure}

    \clearpage
    \section{B.2 test page}
    \blindtext
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \makebox[\paperwidth][c]{\includegraphics[scale=.8]{example-image-b}}
    \end{figure}

    \clearpage
    \section{C.1 test page}
    \blindtext
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \hspace{1.3cm}
        \includegraphics[scale=.8]{example-image-c}
    \end{figure}

    \clearpage
    \section{C.2 test page}
    \blindtext
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
%       \hspace{-1.5cm}
        \includegraphics[scale=.8]{example-image-c}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please see my answer below and clarify which option you want.

Comment: Done. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8611/121944) is relevant to what you asked and centers relative to the text/page margins, i.e, the images enters the left/right margins equally.

Add `\centerline{}`, for example `\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=.8]{example-image-c}}`.

Edit: Alternatively, if you want the image to span from page edge to page edge (or based on paperwidth), then [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26952/121944) is what you're looking for. You'll need to adjust based on figure size.

Here is a solution (I simplified your complicated "MWE"):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperheight=28cm, paperwidth=14cm,%
top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1cm, right=2.5cm,showframe
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
    \hspace{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1.9cm}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\paperwidth]{example-image-a}%
}

\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
    \hspace{-\dimexpr\evensidemargin+1.15cm}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\paperwidth]{example-image-b}%
}

\newpage
\lipsum[3]
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
    \hspace{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1.9cm}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\paperwidth]{example-image-c}%
}

\newpage
\lipsum[4]
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
    \hspace{-\dimexpr\evensidemargin+1.15cm}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\paperwidth]{example-image}%
}

\end{document}\\
```

Comment: mhmm...Well at first, thanks for your response to my issue. And I am sorry for the late response to that.
Maybe I didnt understand your solution, but using `\centerline{}` is resulting in an equal positioning as `\centering`. Which is not what I am after. Both options are centering the image in relation to the text and its width.

Comment: I want to center the image in relation to the actual page, unrelated to the margin definied by the rotated border text.
Furthermore I dont intend to spread the image from edge to edge without any border.

I want the image centered with the same margin on the right and the left side ONLY in relation to the actual paperwidth defined with the geometry package.

Comment: @Djiwahwah I updated my answer. The new solution gives you what you want. But if you want an automated version, then I suggest you post a new question from the answer I gave.